# I'm not getting Push Notification when new message send to user And app is in Background

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-platform

I'm making chat application trying to get push notification when new message received to user from another when app is in background using send notifications between Android devices using Firebase Database, Cloud Messaging and Node.js.

I'm following this blog.Here's

[https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html]

and below is my code which I tried.

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.btnSend) {
        String content = editWriteMessage.getText().toString().trim();
        if (content.length() > 0) {
            editWriteMessage.setText("");
            Message newMessage = new Message();
            newMessage.text = content;
            newMessage.idSender = StaticConfig.UID;
            newMessage.idReceiver = roomId;
            newMessage.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("message/" + roomId).push().setValue(newMessage);
            sendNotificationToUser(newMessage.idReceiver,newMessage.text);
        }
    }
}
public  void sendNotificationToUser(String user, String message) {
    Map notification = new HashMap<>();
    notification.put("username", user);
    notification.put("message", message);
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("notificationRequests").push().setValue(notification);
}
```

By using above codes the username and message is getting saved in real time database in notificationRequests.

And I really don't have idea that how can the push notification is received by this line of code.

```
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("user_"+username);
```

And the most important where do i need to put the above code to make it work.

and also I have created the bucket to host my node.js file.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I misunderstood your problem. Make sure that firebase messaging service is in your manifest.xml file. 
Original:
Use the `functions.database.ref().onCreate()` method. Inside the ref() parameters put the path to your notification requests.

Here's some base code in TypeScript.

```
export const notificationListener = functions.database
.ref('/NotificationRequests/{notification}').onCreate((snapshot, context) =>
{

try {
    admin.initializeApp();
  } catch (e) {
  }


                     //Code to send notification here



return admin.database().ref('/NotificationRequests/' + context.params.notification)
}
)
```

The information you need for the notification is located under `snapshot.child('your path here')`.

[See why and how this works](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions)

Comment: will you please provide me a code snippet because I really don't have idea